# How can a person live on when their soul is sucked by a Dementor?

Tags: harry-potter, dementors

According to Muggle belief, we die when when our soul leaves the body. Wizarding belief seems to believe the same:

> a ghost is an imprint of a departed soul. ...

But the following situation contradicts this:

A person can continue to live on when their soul is taken by a Dementor, albeit without thought and memory.

What happens when a person dies? Does the soul leave the body? If yes how can a person continue to live when his soul is sucked by a Dementor?

Comment: I think it is the other way around, the soul leaves the body when (because) the body dies, not the body dies because the soul leaves.

Answer (score 5):

I believe you have it backwards. Death is a situation that will cause the soul to leave the body. The Dementor's Kiss is another situation that will cause the soul to leave the body.

Lupin makes it very clear that you can survive without your soul:

> You can exist without your soul, you know, as long as your brain and heart are still working. But you’ll have no sense of self anymore, no memory, no . . . anything. There’s no chance at all of recovery. You’ll just — exist. As an empty shell. And your soul is gone forever . . . lost.
> <sub>– HP and the Prisoner of Azkaban, Chapter 12</sub>

Comment: I guess the obvious question then is - why refer to the remaining soulless body as "you?" Wouldn't "you" be wherever the soul is, not where the body is?

Comment: The loss of soul in the Wizarding world might have similar legal and moral grey area as a permanent vegetative state. Even if verifiable that the part of a person that gives them any sense of identity is unrecoverable, it's simply not comfortable to refer to it as "the body." That's pure speculation on my part though as I'm not aware of the long term state of any characters post Kiss. Otherwise, Lupin may simply be speaking in general terms and not the precise language of a "healer" versed in the metaphysics of losing your soul.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, a lot of Muggles don't believe that there are any souls, and thus they believe that people can and do live quite well without souls.

And probably not all Muggles who believe in souls believe that they are as important as Lupin says in Omnificer's answer.  Considering the vast number of Muggle religions that exist, some may believe that souls do all someone's thinking and feeling and everything that makes someone who they are, as Lupin says.  And other Muggle religions may believe that someone's brain and nervous system does all their thinking and feeling, and that he function of a soul is to be merely an immaterial recording device for their personality and identity, to preserve that after their body dies and perhaps be placed into a new body and brain in the afterlife.